# Move files from recycle bin to another location

Tags: versioning

is it possible to move files from the recycle von to an archive library or to a file share?

I'm looking for a way to archive old versions of files to an archive location.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Manually or by code?

Comment: @Moussa an automatic process would be best.

Answer (score 1):

No, you must restore the files out of the recycle bin and then move them to your archive library.

Comment: But is there a way to move only some versions to the archive? I do not want to move all versions.

Comment: I am not aware of any tools that only move old versions. But with code you could develop a tool that exports old versions and deletes them afterwards using the SPFileVersion.Delete method.